# Why vxgplayer keeps loading in https?

Tags: javascript, rtsp

[vxgplayer](https://www.videoexpertsgroup.com/chrome-media-player-plug-in/) demo works fine in HTTP, but in HTTPS it keeps loading , I am using 
`vxgplayer-1.8.21.js` in chrome, files in pnacl folder is successfully loadded.

The debug message output:

```
vxgplayer isFrame: false
vxgplayer browserSupportsPluginPnacl: true
Player vxg_media_player1 - init new player
Player vxg_media_player1 handleMessage: Player Module is ready.
Player vxg_media_player1 handleMessage: PLAYER_INITED
Player vxg_media_player1 - moduleDidLoad
Player vxg_media_player1 - loadSettings
Player: vxg_media_player1 cmd=[setversion] 1.8.21
Player: vxg_media_player1 cmd=[setconnection_timeout] 0
Player: vxg_media_player1 cmd=[setaspectratio] 1
Player: vxg_media_player1 cmd=[setavsync] 1
Player: vxg_media_player1 cmd=[setlatency] 3000000
Player vxg_media_player1 connectToApp
Player vxg_media_player1 connected port=[object Object]
connected port.name=1482113443000
disconnected port.name=1482113443000
```

Why disconnected immedately after connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vxgplayer HTTPS page https://www.videoexpertsgroup.com/nacl_player_api/
should work as expected.
vxgplayer works on HTTP webserver page without restrictions, but
in order to enable vxgplayer onto your own HTTPS server you should send 
"top level domain" name like "https://yourcompany.com" to support@videoexpertsgroup.com for registration in the plugin.

Best Regards,
VideoExpertsGroup Team

Comment: The e-mail has beed sent , may I know why there is such a restriction?